# Integrating QRCode gets force to close in android

Tags: android

I followed all the instructions in this link: http://www.jmanzano.esblog/?p=244#comment-2175. But when I click the `Button` in the `Activity` it not working(force to close).

In log-cat show following error:

```
 8-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.<clinit>(CaptureActivity.java:108)
 08-21 11:59:25.895: E/AndroidRuntime(909):     ... 15 more
```

Comment: make sure that you have zxing source in your project & com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity activity in your manifest file

Comment: ya i done that,after that also getting the same...

Comment: Have you added it in your `Manifest.xml`?

Comment: ya i added...but not gets the output..